# How to exit eclipse debug perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using Java in Eclipse 8 and I accidentally opened this debug perspective. I want to exit this debug perspective, but I don't know how. 
Thanks! 
[image: This is how it looks like now]

Answer (score 37):

As already many authors mentioned, you can click on "java"-perspective tab. You can read more about eclipse in [official user guide](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp).

There are also a plenty of resources on web with eclipse guides/introductions/tutorials.

[image: One-click solution :)]

Answer (score 8):

You see a box named `java` at the right top side? i.e, between `quick access` and `debug` texts. Click it! :)

Comment: This should be chosen as the answer and we can combine the rest of the answers with this!

Answer (score 5):

You can use java button right corner to come back to regular java perspective.

[image: see right corner]

Answer (score 1):

In MyEclipse go to the Top-Right corner. Switch to the required mode using the following Buttons:

1. Open perspective
2. Debug perspective
3. Java perspective
4. MyEclipse Java Enterprise perspective

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 0):

Right top corner! You prolly used the shortcut ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click the project and Open Properties.
2. Then Select Run/Debug Setting from there you will find all the launch Configured.
3. Delete all the launch and Run the application.

Answer (score -1):

On the top right of your window you see that the "Debug" button is active.
To the left of it there is a button for the usual "Java" perspective. You just need to click that :)